# C++ vs Forms Application start cmd

Tags: c++, forms

I want to start the **cmd** when you click a button. This is my current code:

```
Process::Start("cmd");

ProcessStartInfo processtartinfo = new ProcessStartInfo;
processtartinfo.Arguments = "/C help";
processtartinfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle::Hidden;
processtartinfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
Process::Start(processtartinfo);
```

**But it shows me this error (on "ProcessStartInfo"):**

> error C2750: "System::Diagnostics::ProcessStartInfo": "new" cannot be used for this reference Type. Use ''gcnew'' instead.

**And (on "ProcessStartInfo"):**

> error C2664: 'System::Diagnostics::ProcessStartInfo::ProcessStartInfo(const System::Diagnostics::ProcessStartInfo %)' : Conversion of argument 1 of 'System::Diagnostics::ProcessStartInfo *' to 'System::Diagnostics::Process ^' is not possible*

**And (on "Process::Start"):**

> error C2665: "System::Diagnostics::Process::Start": Through none of the 6 overloads all types of arguments could be converted.*

How to fix this?
(If I use gcnew it shows an error on "new")

Comment: You are writing C# code instead of C++/CLI code.  Knowing when to use the ^ hat is very, very important.  Spend a day on a tutorial to get the basics, it will save you (and us) a lot of time.

Comment: Okay. I thought c++ would be more similar to c#...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ProcessStartInfo processtartinfo = new ProcessStartInfo;
```

Above statement is invalid, when you use "new" the object should be pointer

```
ProcessStartInfo* processtartinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
```

will make more sense

As you mentioned , compiler error error C2750: "System::Diagnostics::ProcessStartInfo": "new" cannot be used for this reference Type. Use ''gcnew'' instead.

in this case you should use (^)handle like this:(Managed c++ syntax)

```
ProcessStartInfo^ processtartinfo = gcnew ProcessStartInfo();
```